# systemd-shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize DM devices, ignoring

Tags: systemd, lvm, devices, reboot, kubuntu

Each time I reboot my laptop, that's running Kubuntu 20.04, I see this message right before it reluctantly reboots:

```
systemd-shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize  DM devices, ignoring
```

Also, rebooting takes longer than it should while this message is being displayed.

I've found a bunch of people asking about this, but I haven't yet read one solid answer.

What does this message really mean, and how can I fix this "failure"? The goal is to have no unnecessary delays when I initiate a reboot.

Comment: For me, the message goeas away quickly, no apparent delay

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the delay you are experiencing, but the message `systemd-shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize DM devices, ignoring` may suggest that your root filesystem is on a LVM device and because of that `systemd` cannot detach it. So you can safely ignore that message.

Take a look at https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/15004. There is a mention about a delay in the shutdown too, but it would be necessary more detailed logs to know what's going on.